# Is that the normal behavior that all files can be downloaded in asp.net / IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. Some routes are defined to trigger the controllers

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

However, anyone can download any file in my root folder (where the extension is not blacklisted by IIS like `.asp`, `.conf` ...). Usually, what I would do is a single static folders with my css and img, but here, the whole root folder seems to be static. Is that the normal behavior or did the previous developper did some hack there ?

Comment: Can you give examples of downloadable files that you want to prevent/forbid from being downloaded?

Comment: I don't want to blacklist files but I would prefer to whitelist which is a better security practice. I have files in my root folders such as .dll or .txt files that can be downloaded. There are also some migrations script like .sql that are (hopefully) blockede by IIS.

Comment: It's rather simple: *don't put files there that are meant to be private*. It's a WEB project, not a scratchpad. Or else at least prevent them from being copied/deployed to your hosting enviroments.

Comment: @PeterB Unsure here if it's really that much of a bad practice and not also a bad design of asp.net mvc5. On asp.net mvc 6, it seems that you actually have a static folder (wwwroot). I stubbed on this  [post](https://reviewhostingasp.net/makes-asp-net-mvc-6-outstanding-previous-version/) and apparently we're not the only one storing migrations script in our project...

Comment: Also, some files are meant to be private but still need to be in the project. Thinking here about some excel templates file to generate report that are reserved for admins for example.

Comment: I agree with @PeterB. Also if you do not allow to list the content of the folder, then the users would not know what files can be found there. Because of this even if you have a file there, no one can download it without knowing the file name.

Comment: @Crick3t security by obscurity is terrible opsec.

Comment: @AnonBird I know and that was not my point. The point is: Is that file super secure or not? If yes then don't put it there, put it somewhere else like a file server or in a special folder and set a rule that denies access to that specific folder/file. If not super secure then it does not really matter if they can download it or not.